# ionic angular-adal windows azure active directory custom url scheme

Tags: ios, angularjs, azure, ionic-framework, azure-active-directory

After successfully logged in I'd like to redirect the user back to the app but I don't know how to do that since `Microsoft Windows Azure Active Directory` login doesn't allows me custom url schemes in `redirectUri` parameter, bellow you'll find a screen-shot of the error.

**Reply address 'myscheme://autorize' specified by the request is not a valid URL.**

[image]

Comment: Where do you display the login page? Is it in embedded in webview or actual browser? If you are hosting this initial page as a single page app, you can do the actual app redirect after you receive the token. angular-adal uses oauth2 implicit and token will be returned in redirect url as fragment.

Comment: @OmerCansizoglu: The login shows up into a popup that shows up after pressing the login button; certainly the app goes in the background and it needs to be called again. I've seen something related to Azure AD registering a custom url scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option that I had was to switch to native application, rather then `Web application` which will support only `http` or `https`

[image]

Comment: is there any downside to this switch?

Comment: @GregorSrdic: if the end result is a mobile application no, otherwise I'd recommend to use Web Application. (short answer: **no** & depends by scenario)